# foreach loop inline instead of Horizontal

Tags: php, html, css

Sorry for this newbie question, i'm looping my db to get the list of my categories

```
foreach($cats as $cat) { 
                        echo "<li><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\""; 
                        echo Helper::getActive(array('category' => $cat['id'])); 
                        echo ">"; 
                        echo Helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']); 
                        echo "</a></li>";
```

and the list displayed Horizontal, how can i display it inline?
in css i would just have done: `display: inline;`

Comment: Can you show by screenshot what you are getting and what you want to be?

Comment: Why can you not add `display: inline;` to your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question, horizontal normally is an inline, or inline-block element, but the answer would be the same regardless:

```
echo "<li style='display:block;'><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
```

Simple and easy. Just place an inline style in the `<li>`.
Or, if you are like me, and hate inline styles, just use a class:

```
echo "<li class='test'><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
```

Then, just but the CSS in your the `<head>`, or in an external stylesheet:

```
<style>
li.test{
display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @DennisSchwarts you're very welcome. It is a good practice to mark the answer you are using as accepted(the little check mark beside it). Not only does it keep that answer easier for people with the same problem to see, it gives the answerer a 15 reputation bonus, which is always nice :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to you li tag and modify it using a CSS stylesheet.

```
 echo "<li class='inline-list'><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
```

Comment: i can't post images :(